# how to load two dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string containing many lines of the following format:
`<`word1`><`101`>`
`<`word2`><`102`>`
`<`word3`><`103`>`
I know how to load each line into an array cell using this:

```
var arrayOfStuff = stringOfStuff.split("\n");
```

But the above makes one array cell per line, I need a two-dimensional array.
Is there a way to do that using similar logic to the above without having to re-read and re-process the array.  I know how to do it in two phases, but would rather do it all in one step.
Thanks in advance,
Cliff

Comment: Could you provide an example of the dataset you are trying to parse, and the desired results?

Comment: I would but this comment block won't let me add returns.

Comment: You can edit your question and put it there.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're hoping for something like Python's list comprehension (e.g. `[line.split(" ") for line in lines.split("\n")]`), but Javascript has no such feature.  The very simplest way to get the same result in Javascript is to use a loop:

```
var lines = lines.split("\n");

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i] = lines[i].split(" ");

    // or alternatively, something more complex using regexes:
    var match = /<([^>]+)><([^>]+)>/.exec(lines[i]);
    lines[i] = [match[1], match[2]];
}
```

Comment: Although it's possible to do multidimensional arrays in javascript... wouldn't be more correct to use an object?

Comment: Yes, this loop will produce a two-dimensional array.  Whether it makes more sense to store it as an array of arrays or an array of objects is too situational to cover in a short answer.  :-)

Comment: Yeah ... that's the two-phase approach I was talking about ... was hoping for one ... but oh well ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really. There are no native javascript functions that return a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to parse a CSV for example, you can do

```
var parsedStuff = [];
stringOfStuff.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n')  // Normalize newlines
    // Parse lines and dump them in parsedStuff.
    .replace(/.*/g, function (_) { parsedStuff.push(_ ? _.split(/,/g)) : []; })
```

Running

```
stringOfStuff = 'foo,bar\n\nbaz,boo,boo'
var parsedStuff = [];
stringOfStuff.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n')
    .replace(/.*/g, function (_) { parsedStuff.push(_ ? _.split(/,/g)) : []; })
JSON.stringify(parsedStuff);
```

outputs

```
[["foo","bar"],[],["baz","boo","boo"]]
```

You can adjust the `/,/` to suite whatever record separator you use.